# Selecting from a subquery instead of an entity with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Is this possible using QueryOver or CreateCriteria:

```
SELECT FooName, SUM(FooAmount)
FROM (
     SELECT
         (SELECT Name FROM Foo
         WHERE Foo.BarId = Bar.Id) as FooName,
         FooAmount
     FROM Bar
) as inner_query
GROUP BY FooName
```

Please note that this query has been constructed for demonstration purposes. I am not interested in adding relationships between entities, rewriting the query itself etc. Also, the app is setup to take advantage of query construction using CreateCriteria - it is not possible to change it to HQL.

It is possible to construct the inner query in NHibernate as a detatched criteria. The problem is getting NHibernate to select from the inner query, instead of over an entity. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate - as typical ORM tool - provides query/domain manipulation language(es) *(HQL, QueryOver, Criteria...)* on top of object model. FROM clause is always defined by the `Object` mapping.

The options you have

- introduce new *readonly* object mapped to view (or subselect instead of table)
- use `session.CreateSQLQuery()` to get full access to underlying structured query language (SQL)